# Can Delphi be used to create extensions for Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, delphi, google-chrome-extension, firemonkey

Yes or not. If yes, are there code examples anywhere? I'd like to create a tool like Google Dictionay extension, i.e. you can click a word and obtain a translation like a pop-up menu. Can it be done with Delphi for a browser (like Chrome)? How?

Comment: That would be a no, they're web based. Either way, Google is killing them off... **EDIT** Actually that's Chrome **apps** which they're killing off; extensions are different.

Comment: It would be crazy to kill off the extensions, they are awesome tools!

Comment: It's not specfically for creating Chrome extensions, but you might take a look at https://www.elevatesoft.com/products?category=ewb

Comment: The [What are extensions?](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) official page states: "_They are built on web technologies such as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Extension files are zipped into a single .crx package that the user downloads and installs. This means extensions do not depend on content from the web, unlike ordinary web apps._" So technically, yes. Delphi can produce any file format including the above. Whether it is practical is probably up for debate.

Comment: @Ron The question is not whether the source files can be created by a Delphi program, but whether the source files can be written in the Delphi language.

Comment: @Peter Why are you so keen to use Delphi?

Comment: @ David Heffernan Because I only know Delphi. I used Delphi to make all kinds of pieces of software but I am a 42 old Romanian and only studied in school many many years ago the language Pascal. Delphi I learned alone. It's counterproductive for me to learn anything else at my age. Besides, I LOVE Delphi. Not so much since Delphi 7 but it's awesome to create mobile apps now, until a few months ago I only created desktop apps.

Answer (score 3):

No. Chrome Extensions are web based. They are a collection of HTML / JS / CSS files which are hosted directly inside Chrome. However, you can use Delphi to build a web server which your Chrome Extension can interact with.

Comment: I didn't vote but I think "not necessarily" is a strange answer to whether something can be done or not.

Comment: @Sertac Actually I said "No" before I edited. I edited because of the downvote.

Comment: @Sertac Funny thing, this whole question sparked my interest into building a Chrome Extension creator using Delphi, and I already have a custom component in the works to be able to build one (generates manifest, etc.), plus an app to actually provide all the tools to build one (including SynEdit, ChromeTabs, and some other Delphi goodies). So, that's why I changed it to "Not necessarily"...